# IIS has arithmetic overflow when viewing worker processes

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, coldfusion

Using IIS v7.5.7600 and clicking on 'Worker Processes' I get this error pop up:

> There was an error while performing this operation.
>
> Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

This is on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1 run by a well-known hosting company.

If I run `appcmd list config` on the command line there are no complaints, suggesting the applicationHost.config file is valid.

Could the 'arithmetic' perhaps refer to calculating values to display in these columns:
[image: Screenshot of IIS Worker Processes display, taken from a different machine]

I'd rather not have to reinstall IIS as we have several live ASP.NET and ColdFusion websites, all working correctly, and we'd like to avoid downtime. But equally, I'd like to use the Worker Processes feature to investigate a problem (possibly hackers).

**Perhaps there is a way to fix it without switching it off for too long?**

Comment: I'm a bit stuck, as Google had nothing for me but a threat of a ColdFusion bug. It is just such an odd error to get from a finished product, and I cannot find any Windows Event Viewer entries that logged the problem.

Comment: It sounds like a possible issue with the values in the applicationhost.config file... are you able to view previous versions of that?
https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/introduction-to-applicationhostconfig

Comment: This is a very sensible idea, thank you. Sadly the IIS history folders do not go back in time far enough. I've also used APPCMD.EXE and it doesn't have any complaints about the config file, which I assume it is checking against the schema. Could there still be a dodgy numerical value somewhere in it?

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a known answer, with evidence, I am forced to conclude I am probably suffering from the ColdFusion bug logged at https://www.elliottsprehn.com/cfbugs/bugs/82203 which states that...

> Closed Bug 82203 (Connector Installer (wsconfig.jar)) Submitted By:
>   Ankur Srivastava on Tue Feb 23 2010
>
> On Windows 2008 64 bit , IIS 7 and CF 9 64 bit.
>
> The performance counters dialog box under server manager (of windows
>   2008)is fully populated prior to the CF installation. Also, the worker
>   processes are listed just fine with no error.
>
> after installing CF 9 and didnot make connector with IIS 7 under in
>   IIS manager > Worker Processes throws the error :
>
> “There was an error while performing this operation. Arithmetic
>   operation resulted in an overflow.”
>
> And in Server Manager > Diagnostics >Monitoring Tools > Performance
>   Monitor > click ADD , performance counters dialog box is empty after
>   CF installation.
>
> Product:  ColdFusion 9.0